# Formatting multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I'm doing a project in CakePHP, and I need get a multidimensional array to convert a JSON with json_encode(). My problem is that the result don't begin from zero.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Steve Jobs
                [rol] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Bill Gates
                [rol] => 8
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Bill Gates
                [rol] => 6
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Bill Gates
                [rol] => 6
            )

    )

)
```

My code to generate that array is:

```
foreach ($docentes_secciones as $i => $itm):
    $j = $itm->seccion_id;
    $docentesSecciones[$j][$i]['nombre'] = $nombrePersona[$itm->perfil_id];
    $docentesSecciones[$j][$i]['rol'] = $itm->rol_id;

endforeach;
```

And I want my array with this format

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Steve Jobs
                [rol] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Bill Gates
                [rol] => 8
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nombre] => Bill Gates
                [rol] => 6
            )

    )

)
```

How can I get my array in the last format?

EDIT:

```
$i_aux = 1;
$j = 0;
foreach ($docentes_secciones as $itm):
    $i = $itm->seccion_id;
    if($i_aux != $i)
        $j = 0;

    $docentesSecciones[$i][$j]['nombre'] = $nombrePersona[$itm->perfil_id];
    $docentesSecciones[$i][$j]['rol'] = $itm->rol_id;
    if($i_aux == $i)
        $j++;
    $i_aux = $i;

endforeach;
```

That work for me, but I want to make that more efficient.

Comment: `$j = $itm->seccion_id;
    $docentesSecciones[$j]` --- you explicitly set it to some value.

Comment: @zerkms I tried but don't work

Comment: What does the output of this: `$docentes_secciones` and this `$nombrePersona` look like?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: it doesn't begin from zero because within the foreach you set the value of $j with the value of the id of your table, didn't you?
And I don't think your table ids start from zero right?
You could try with two for loops instead of a foreach. Maybe something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($docentes_secciones); $i++){
     for ($j = 0; $j < count($docuentes_secciones[$i]); $j++){
         $docentesSecciones[$i][$j]['nombre'] = $nombrePersona[$i]['perfil_id'];
         $docentesSecciones[$i][$j]['rol'] = [$i]['rol_id'];
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't work :/  I make that     $i_aux = 1;
    $j = 0;
   foreach ($docentes_secciones as $itm):
        $i = $itm->seccion_id;
        if($i_aux != $i)
            $j = 0;

        $docentesSecciones[$i][$j]['nombre'] = $nombrePersona[$itm->perfil_id];
        $docentesSecciones[$i][$j]['rol'] = $itm->rol_id;
        if($i_aux == $i)
            $j++;
        $i_aux = $i;
    
    endforeach;